# How do I use gravity form fields on a thank you page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters, gravityforms

I’m using gravity forms in WordPress and have set it up to redirect to a thank you page.

I want to pull the persons name from the query string that gf produces but I have no idea how to get this on the the page in WordPress.

All I need is:

“Thank you NAME for contacting us. We’ll be in touch within 24 hours.”

Can anyone tell me how to pull the name from the url and print it on the page as in the above example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[GF Post Content Merge Tags](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-post-content-merge-tags/) provides the ability to include submitted data in page content via Gravity Forms' merge tags.

[image]